# Is the full Net 4 Framework required to use Code First database generation in our software?

Tags: .net-4.0, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

We are currently migrating our code from VB6 to Net4. We are now at the stage that we will convert the old Access databases to SQLCompact 4.0 and access this using the Entity Framework. It was very easy to add fields and tables to the old Access databases when we updated our application. Now, using the Entity Framework we intend to make use of the Code Migrations package to be able to update the client's database when we release new versions of our application.

Is the Full Framework necessary for this? That would be a possible problem as the Net 4 Client Profile is quite common nowadays, but the Full Framework most certainly is not.

I am open to other suggestions ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a basic console app targeting .NET 4 Client Profile and using EF 4.3.  It worked fine, and only took about 5 minutes.